# How to make one view from one app be shown in all urls in Django?

Tags: django, django-urls

I have created an app for the main template of my project (All other templates inherit from this one). The template includes header, footer and an **aside** in which i can add and delete posts from the admin panel. Now, when rendering all the templates everything (header, footer and the respective `{% block content %}`) is shown correctly but not the aside because i'm not passing any url to the view managing it.

I'm trying to pass that view to every URL of my project so the aside is always shown.
I just dont get the way of doing it.

**Just to clarify:** Following the code i'm going to show now the aside is shown in `localhost:8000` only. Not in `localhost:8000/inicio` nor any other url.

**Aside views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import asides

def post_aside(request):
    aside_posts = asides.objects.all()
    return render(request, "main/main.html", {"aside_posts" : aside_posts})
```

**urls.py of the app with the aside**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [

    path('', views.post_aside, name='main'),

]
```

**urls.py of the project**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls), 
    path('', include('main.urls')),
    path('inicio/', include('inicio.urls')),
    path('galeria/', include('galeria.urls')),
    path('mapa/', include('mapa.urls')),
    path('contacto/', include('contacto.urls')),
    path('usuarios/', include('usuarios.urls')),
]
urlpatterns+=static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: there are multiple ways to achive that. I would suggest to write a little API and call it via ajax from your base.html Insert the data to the HTML from there.....

Comment: @hansTheFranz isn't there a way of doing it simpler or just sticking to the django docs? I've navigating through these and i feel like i'm missing something.

Comment: you could put what you want in your base template, and write your own context processor https://medium.com/better-programming/django-quick-tips-context-processors-da74f887f1fc Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create `context_processor.py` in app where your asides model exists.
Then add inside:

```
from .models import asides

def website_content(request):
    context = {
       'aside_posts': asides.objects.all(),
    }
    return context
```

Then in your `settings.py` in `context_processors` list add on the end:
`<your_app>.context_processor.website_content`
it should look like:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'aside.context_processor.website_content',  # HERE PATH TO YOUR CONTEXT PROCESSOR FUNCTION
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

after this use `{% for post in aside_posts %}` in your template anywhere you want.